# Varnish disabled, but still add a custom header (hostname)

Tags: varnish

Why in Varnish 4.0 can't I see my custom header set on the response ?

```
sub vcl_recv {
   // disable varnish for now
   return (pass);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.X-Backend = "my_custom_hostname";
    return (deliver);
}
```

It was working some times ago, (in varnish 3.x or without http2 on nginx backend, don't know which factor is it).

Do you know what's causing the fact that i can't see my `X-Backend` custom header in the http response ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `vcl_deliver` if you want to make sure that the custom header goes into the response that clients (browsers) get:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.X-Backend = "my_custom_hostname";
    return (deliver);
}
```